# How do I use a LWC to execute an Einstein Next Best Action Strategy?

Tags: lightning-web-components, rest-api, einstein

I am attempting to create a custom front end for Einstein Next Best Action using Lightning Web Component on the Account record page. I would appreciate some help writing the fetch() request since what I am trying isn't working. I've never written a fetch() in Salesforce before and it's been around 2 years since I last wrote a fetch() in JavaScript.

The documentation I found does not seem to be a complete answer.

[Connect REST API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_nba_recommendations.htm#connect_resources_nba_recommendations)

[Unofficial SF Use the Next Best Action REST API to execute a strategy and retrieve recommendation reactions](https://unofficialsf.com/use-the-next-best-action-rest-api-to-execute-a-strategy-and-retrieve-recommendation-reactions/)

According to these two docs, they make it seem that all that is needed is the URL, method, and body. Which would lead me to this:

```
connectedCallback(){
    fetch('/connect/recommendation-strategies/CharlesSpike2/recommendations',
    {
        method:"POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "contextRecordId": "a2ic00000013FwSAAU",
            "maxResults": 5             
        })
    }).then((response) => {
        return response.json(); // returning the response in the form of JSON
    }).then((jsonResponse) => {
        console.log('jsonResponse', jsonResponse);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('callout error ===> '+ JSON.stringify(error));
    })
}
```

However, that doesn't seem to work. I would assume that I would need either mode: 'cors', credentials: 'include', or maybe even headers: { contentType: "application/json" }?

Ive replaced part of the URL with instance_name, but the error I receive is:

```
Refused to connect to 'https://instance_name/services/data/v45.0/connect/recommendation-strategies/CharlesSpike2/recommendations' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https://api.bluetail.salesforce.com https://staging.bluetail.salesforce.com https://preprod.bluetail.salesforce.com blob: *.cs14.visual.force.com https://instance_name--c.cs14.content.force.com https://cs14.salesforce.com".
```

URL options seem to start with /connect or /services/data/v45.0/connect, or even https://instance_name/services/data/v45.0/connect.

Does credentials: 'include' work? It seems strange to setup Authorization and OAuth to call from inside Salesforce to a Salesforce endpoint.

Thank you for the help,

Charles